# Display predifined HTML element with jquery validation plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate

I want to display symbol with jquery validation plugin. If I not entered my value correctly jquery validation should give error (it is ok) and show my custom symbol (`.validation-incorrect`). After that validation get pass I want show `.validation-correct` symbol. How to do that? Here my code

```
<div class="col-xs-4">
   <input type="text" class="form-control" name="roleName" placeholder="Role name" />                       
</div>
<b class="fa fa-check control-label validation-correct roleName-validation" 
                data-toggle="tooltip" title="You have entered it correctly">
</b>
<b class="fa fa-remove control-label validation-incorrect roleName-validation" 
     data-toggle="tooltip" title="You should be entered " id="roleName-validation">
</b>
```

Comment: You need to make an attempt at doing this yourself and then show us where you got stuck. We're not a code-writing service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you want to show an icon for an invalid entry and then change when the entry is valid.  You probably want to start by adding an [onchange](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onchange.asp) event to the item you wish to validate.  Use something like

```
    <input type="text" onchange="validateEntry(this);"/>
```

to trigger the "validateEntry" javascript function (passing in the control object using `this`.  For example the `validateEntry` function below validates whether the input text is greater than 3

```
    function validateEntry(inputToValidate) {
        if (inputToValidate.value.length < 3) {
            document.getElementById('inputThing').style.backgroundColor = '#F6CECE';
            hide(document.getElementById('validSymbolsId'));
            show(document.getElementById('invalidSymbolsId'));
        } else { 
            document.getElementById('inputThing').style.backgroundColor = '#FFFFFF';
            hide(document.getElementById('invalidSymbolsId'));
            show(document.getElementById('validSymbolsId'));
        }
    }
```

You can use [JQuery](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_hide_show.asp) to hide or show elements but if you don't have that you can use something like below.

```
    function hide(element) {
        element.style.display = 'none';
    }

    function show(element) {
        element.style.display = '';
    }
```